# Posting form data inside webmethod in csharp

Tags: asp.net, post, webmethod

I want to post some data in to a form inside web method .
And i want to post that form to a external url.
I have to pass some data when the form is submitted.
I want to redirect to the given url by submitting the form which is written in body onload.

How can I redirect to the url within the web method.? Can anybody help me on this..
Below is my code.

```
[webMethod]
public static void RedirectUrl()
{
string pspId = "test";
string orderId="1000";
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
                    string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", "form1"));

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
                    string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", "form1", "Post", Url));

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
                    string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", "PSPID", pspId));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
                    string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", "orderID", orderId));             

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" self.location.href=\"Test.aspx?Return=1\";");

Comment: I want to submit the form to the url with paramyters .I did not get your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Url);
```